# Using a pivot table to create a tree-like structure and how to create efficient queries?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

In our codebase we have a set of models that represent AI models and their training data. When people train new models they are usually trained off an existing AI model in the database, and we wanted to track a sort of "versioning" of these models, so that people can use prior versions, and create branching revisions.

our models look like so:

```
class TrainingRun(models.Model):
   from_model = models.ForeignKey('api.AIModel', related_name='subsequent_runs')
   to_model = models.OneToOneField('api.AIModel', related_name='prior_run')
   hyperparameters = models.JSONField(default={})
   # etc.


class AIModel(models.Model):
   save_path = models.URLField(max_length=200, null=True)
   bookmarked_by = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User', related_name='bookmarks')
   # etc.
```

we're expecting this data to come out looking something "linked-list"y so that users can create branching revisions to prior models, bookmark ones that they like etc.

the data structure might come out to look something like a git revision history, without merge functionality but I'm wondering is this is a good idea inside a relational database with foreign keys etc.

Also I am wondering if there is an efficient way to traverse the list of objects in a way where I could, say, get a list of any users inside the tree that have subscribed to a bookmark? It seems like no matter which way you slice it you'll be doing a lot of joins, but is there maybe a way to group it into one query?

I'm thinking maybe there is also generally a better way to do this that perhaps doesn't use relational databases or linked lists in general.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this by using [postgres ltree](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ltree.html), there is a django package that supports this called [django-ltree](https://github.com/mariocesar/django-ltree)

the example would work like so

```
from django_ltree.models import TreeModel

class AIModel(TreeModel):
   save_path = models.URLField(max_length=200, null=True)
   bookmarked_by = models.ManyToManyField('auth.User', related_name='bookmarks')
```

and get a list of children/parents via a query such as

```
am = AIModel.object.first()
ancestors = am.ancestors()
descendants = am.descendants()
```